# How to make an if for being float or not?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if i can make an if loop for the next example:

```
a=3;
b=2;
double c=a/b;
// if c is float cout<<"c is float";
// if c is int cout << "c is int";
```

I really don't know how to write the last two lines as c++ code .. anyone can help?

Comment: you'd get an int, since both values are ints. if you had `a=3; b=2.0`, then you'd get a float, because b is a float.

Comment: @MarcB: No, the type of `c` is determined by its declaration, not by the value stored in it.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? `int`? `float`? `double`?

Comment: Do you mean if a is not divisible by b ((a % b != 0) ? "float" : "int"). If c is declared as int would be int even if b don't divide a. `int a = 3, b = 2, c = a/b;` c is the integer 1

Comment: if i made c double .. what i mean with float is there are no decimal numbers??

Comment: `c` is either float or not, there is no way it can change.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to ask how to check if a value has digits after the decimal place or not.

Comment: Exactly NetVipeC .. thank you

Comment: @KeithThompson, Marc B is correct - the division is performed on ints, then the result is converted to a double for assignment to `c`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, but the question was understood as "what type is c", in which case the type of the expression result is not relevant - the type of c is what it was declared as. It's moot anyway, because that wasn't really the OP's question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Also, MarcB *assumed* that a and b are ints, but the code doesn't actually show what type they are.

Comment: @JBentley good point, I made the same assumption.

Comment: @user3803421 `if` is a conditional statement, not a loop. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if the division will result in a whole number, you can check the remainder directly. This is more direct than dealing with the floating point.

```
if (a % b != 0) cout << "c is float";
if (a % b == 0) cout << "c is int";
```

Of course this only works if `a` and `b` are integers. If they aren't, you can use [`modf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf) to see the fractional part of the result is zero.

```
double dummy;
if (modf(c, &dummy) == 0.0) cout << "c is int";
```

Comment: That works only if `a` and `b` are of some integer type. There is no `%` operator for `double`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure you're stating the question incorrectly. The type of `c` (`int`, `float`, whatever) is determined by its declaration, not by whatever value happens to be stored in it.  Given:

```
double c;
c = 4;
```

the `int` value `4` is implicitly converted from `int` to `double`, so the value of `c` is `4.0`. It's still of *type* `double`.

I think what you're trying to do is determine whether the current value of `c` is a whole number. If its value is not too large, you can do this:

```
if (c == (int)c) {
    std::cout << "The value of C is a whole number\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "The value of c contains a fractional part\n";
}
```

`(int)c` converts the value of `c` to `int`, truncating any fractional part. If that doesn't change the value, there was no fractional part.

To allow for arbitrary values, you can use the `floor` function:

```
#include <cmath>

if (c == floor(c)) {
    std::cout << "The value of C is a whole number\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "The value of c contains a fractional part\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `==` in the if?

Answer (score 1):

[`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) gives you the type of an identifier, but I'm not sure what you're getting at. If you've defined `c` as a float, it will be a float whether or not `a` is divisible by `b`.

**Probably what you need is `if (a%b == 0)`**, which has nothing to do with the type of `c`. This will work if `a` and `b` are integers.

If you just have a float `c` and want to check if it's decimal part is zero, see Keith Thompson's answer using `floor()`, but look out for floating point precision issues.

Anyway, here's how to use `typeid` for what it's worth:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int n;
    if (typeid(n) == typeid(int))
        cout << "n is an integer.\n";
}
```

Comment: Answers the question as stated, but not what the OP actually meant to ask.

Comment: @KeithThompson That was my hunch too. What s/he wants is `if (a%b == 0)` but it doesn't hurt to learn about `typeid` (or maybe it does!).

Comment: Of course `if (a%b == 0)` works only of `a` and `b` are of some integer type.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int a=3;
    int b=2;

    if((a % b != 0)
    {
        cout<<"float";
    }

    return 0;
}
```